# Python to add the hour,minutes, and second to the time that has been created

Tags: python-3.x

How do I add the hour,min, and second to the time that I have created?

Code:

```
import datetime

time_entry = input('Enter a time in hh:mm:ss format:')
hours, minutes, second = map(int, time_entry.split(':'))
t = datetime.time(hours, minutes, second)

h = int(input('Hours:'))
m = int(input('Minutes:'))
s = int(input('Seconds:'))

print('Current time is:',t)

t1 = datetime.time(hours + h, minutes + m, second + s)
print('New time is:',t1)
```

i want it to come out like this:

```
Enter a time in hh:mm:ss format:23:23:23
Hours:2
Minutes:2
Seconds:2
Current time is: 23:23:23
New time is: 1:25:25
```

but I got:

```
t1 = datetime.time(hours + h, minutes + m, second + s)
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

Comment: Pls post your code along with your `log` here instead of linking it to a snapshot.

Comment: ok...I have edited it

Comment: And your Input and expected output

Comment: What result do you expect if `hours` ends up greater than 23?

Comment: Thought he might realise his mistake when he wrote the output :D

Comment: I'm expecting it to be a new day like after 23 p.m after I have added another 2 hour, for example, it will come out to be 1 a.m

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `timedelta` object:

```
from datetime import timedelta
t1 = datetime.time(hours, minutes, second) + timedelta(seconds=s, minutes=m, hours=h)
```

and in there `s` and `m` can be greater than 59, and `h` greater 23 without problem

Comment: it will print out like this : t = datetime.time(hours, minutes, second)
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Comment: @AbdHakimKarim It will of coursel also complain about `hours`, `minutes`, `second`, `s`, `m` and `h`. *You have to put the above in your existing program*, otherwise all those names will throw an error.